# How to copy a file located in different remote directories to a single local directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, copy

I have multiple directories under a main directory in a remote cluster that carries a specific file. I'm trying to do a remote copy of those files in multiple directories into a single local directory. The regular expression

> scp -r username@cluster:folderpath/*/file1 .

will not work in this scenario since it will over-write the files. How can I copy such that

1. I either have the files with an iterating suffix (such as file1_1,
   file1_2) or,
2. Ideally with the folder name concatenated to the filename.

It will also be helpful if you can comment on how this approach can be extended to file extensions (*.txt, *.out etc).

Comment: Take a look at `rsync`, it will maintain folder structure.

Comment: You should probably put apostrophes around the username@cluster:folderpath/*/file to quote it, otherwise in some shells/scenarios the * will be used as a *local* wildcard.  Rsync is a better choice, but the advice still applies to its args. The tar command is also well suited to this, with something like: ssh cluster 'cd folderpath && tar czf - *' | tar xzvBpf -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rsync` you can copy recursively only including the file you want:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir source1 source2 target
$ touch source1/a source2/a source2/b
$ rsync --include=a --recursive --relative 'localhost:/tmp/source*/a' target
$ ls -R target
target:
tmp

target/tmp:
source1  source2

target/tmp/source1:
a

target/tmp/source2:
a
```

If you want to include `a` from any level below `source*` you can use double asterisks:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir source1 source1/subdir source2 target
$ touch source1/a source1/subdir/a source2/a source2/b
$ rsync --include=a --recursive --relative 'localhost:/tmp/source*/a' 'localhost:/tmp/source*/**/a' target
$ ls -R target
target:
tmp

target/tmp:
source1  source2

target/tmp/source1:
a  subdir

target/tmp/source1/subdir:
a

target/tmp/source2:
a
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. How should I modify the rsync if I don't know the depth at which the file a is located. For example it can be in source1/subsource1/a & source2/a